# PPPOE connecting in debian

Tags: debian, pppoe, dsl

a network has a pppoe VPN connection and after i searched how to enable it ,i reached the command pppoeconf , when i used it , it showed me for enabling and disabling the vpn via command : sudo pon dsl-provider  and for disabling it :
sudo poff , but i lost my regular connection after i disable it.

[Wired Connection Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCncf.png)

as you can see my LAN icon is kind of lost and i don't know anything in detail about networking in Debian or in General either.

i do have internet when i enable the pppoe connection , i will lost it when i disable it.

here is the detail of my machine:

[My Debiab Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIl6N.png)